# cuda: using global variables for device memory

Tags: variables, memory, cuda, global

I have a question regarding how to use proper variables in cuda code. My program has lot of arrays, which need to be accessed in different functions and I want to avoid passing them and want to use global variables and 2D mallocpitch arrays, instead of flattened 1D array. So, I am thinking of something like this:

```
__device__ double * dataPtr ;
__device__ size_t dataPitch;
....
int main()
{
 double * dataPtrLoc; size_t dataPitchLoc;
cudaMallocPitch( (void**) &dataPtrLoc, &dataPitchLoc, width*sizeof(double), height);
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dataPtr, &dataPtrLoc, sizeof(dataPtrLoc));
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dataPitch, &dataPitchLoc, sizeof(dataPitchLoc));
...
}
```

Does it look like a good way to have global 2D device data? Can you give suggestions?

Edit: I made this program and it compiles and runs fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__device__ int *d_gridPtr;
__device__ size_t d_gridPitch;

__device__ int valij(int ii, int jj)
{
  int* row = (int*)((char*)d_gridPtr + ii * d_gridPitch);
  return (row[jj]);
}

__global__ void printval()
{
  int val0, val1, val2, val3;
  val0= valij(0,0);
  val1= valij(0,1);
  val2= valij(1,0);
  val3= valij(1,1);
  printf("%d %d %d %d \n", val0, val1, val2, val3);
}

int main()
{
  size_t d_gridPitchLoc;
  int * d_gridPtrLoc;  
  cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_gridPtrLoc, &d_gridPitchLoc, 2 * sizeof(int), 2);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_gridPtr, & d_gridPtrLoc, sizeof(d_gridPtrLoc));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_gridPitch, &d_gridPitchLoc, sizeof(float));

  int h_mem[2*2]={0,1,100,4};  
  size_t hostpitch = 2* sizeof(int);
  cudaMemcpy2D(d_gridPtrLoc,d_gridPitchLoc,h_mem,hostpitch,2*sizeof(int),2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  printval<<<1,1>>> ();
  cudaDeviceReset();  
}
```

Comment: That code won't work - the copy to dataPtr is wrong. But constant memory would make more sense for this sort of thing.

Comment: Whether the data is constant or irrelevant, you are only storing the pointer to the global memory data in constant memory, not the data itself. This is how kernel arguments are implemented in Fermi GPUs anyway.

Comment: My data is not constant. I remember reading that constant memory is not necessarily constant, just cached global memory (not sure though). So, do you still think, constant memory would work?

Comment: So, do you suggest, using __ device __ __ constant __ double *dataPtr and copying memory symbol to it?

Comment: Keeping 2D data as 2D in CUDA could improve performance particularly if there is spatial locality in mem access (coalescing etc will be obvious to the compiler in both dimensions). Also, if your array will fit in _constant_ device memory, then declare it like this:
`__constant__ __device__ int dMyContantArray[1024];`

Answer (score 1):

If all threads of a warp or block access the same read-only global memory address (e.g. array index) at the same time, then consider storing that read-only global data in a `__constant__` memory array instead.  If you write to the data, then you can't use `__constant__`.

If your array is read-only and your access pattern has strong 2D locality (within a warp and/or block), consider using textures instead.